# Java in BlueJ - how to stop an animation running once an object has traveled a specific distance?

Tags: java, bluej

I've been asked to create a program in BlueJ that animates a specified number of balls, of random sizes, bouncing which I've succeeded in. I just can't work out how to do the last part which is to stop the animation after the last ball has left the screen (no sooner and no later). This is what I have so far:

```
// make them bounce
    boolean finished =  false;
    while(!finished) {
        myCanvas.wait(100);           // small delay
        for(BouncingBall ball : balls) {
            ball.move();
        // stop once ball has travelled a certain distance on x axis
        if((ball.getXPosition() >= 550 + 32*numberOfBalls) ) {
            finished = true;
        }
```

The line

```
if((ball.getXPosition() >= 550 + 32*numberOfBalls) )
```

Was provided by the book, and I can't work out where the 32 has come from which probably isn't helping - it doesn't seem to be referred to anywhere else in the code.

I've tried other things such as:

```
if((ball.getXPosition() >= 550 + 32*numberOfBalls) && (ball.getXPosition() <= (550 + ball.getDiameter()) )
```

But it still stops the animation a little while after the last ball has left the screen.

Any advice would be appreciated, I'm just at a loss as to what to do with it.
Many thanks.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiopu.png) of the animation working, I'm wanting to get it so that it stops running as soon as all of the pink balls have left the screen.

Comment: Can you add a small drawing? Which shows the idea, you try to achieve.

Comment: The `32*numberOfBalls` looks suspicious.

Comment: What is the X demension min and max? What is the diameter of the ball ?

Comment: The diameter of the balls is generated randomly with 

int ballDiameter = random.nextInt(120);

I'm not sure what you mean by the X dimension min max? The canvas size is 600 by 500.

Comment: __Q:__ At which X position do the balls start?  __Q:__ How mutch does `move()`, move the balls? And in which direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
if (ball.getXPosition() >= 550) {

}
```

As in current situation, say there are 10 balls, then only if the balls are 550 + 32*numberOfBalls (meaning 32 * 10 + 550 = 870). Probably there will never happen....

Or add the complete code, and not just the snippet, as now it is to unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I did some search on **if((ball.getXPosition() >= 550 + 32*numberOfBalls) )** and it turned out to be if the balls have been distributed evenly. So this will make sense. Otherwise you have to check if all balls are out of the screen, by using **if(ball.getXPosition() >= 550)** alone.

Also, as you mentioned, you have to add the diameter of your ball to the condition. Therefore:

```
if((ball.getXPosition() + ball.getDiameter()) >= 550) { }
```

Refs:

http://lists.bluej.org/pipermail/bluej-discuss/2006-March/005457.html

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/33178-need-randomly-change-size-programs-balls.html